# Case sensitive Sorting in tanstack react-table v8

Tags: reactjs, react-table, tanstack, react-table-v8

I want case-sensitive sorting but It's not working in Tanstack react-table v8.

In the documentation I can see `alphanumericCase` sensitive is there. But I'm not able to understand how to apply this mode.
[image]

Code:

```
const table = useReactTable<TData>({
data: dataMemoised,
columns: columnsMemoised,
state: {
  columnVisibility,
  columnOrder,
  columnPinning,
  rowSelection,
  sorting,
},
enableRowSelection: true,
enableSortingRemoval: false,
onRowSelectionChange: setRowSelection,
onColumnVisibilityChange: setColumnVisibility,
onColumnOrderChange: setColumnOrder,
onColumnPinningChange: setColumnPinning,
getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
getRowId,
onSortingChange: setSorting,
getSortedRowModel: getSortedRowModel(),


})
```

Am I missing to add anything here?

Answer (score 0):

try this inside your column :
`sortingFn: 'alphanumericCaseSensitive'`

Comment: This answer would benefit from additional explanation on how you deduced this solution and how it will resolve the issue.